# running javafx on visual studio code mostly does not run

Tags: java, javafx, runtime-error

I hope you are all well,
I have problem in visual studio code while running the javafx code, I have added the javafx  SDK library to the java project, also I have added the run configuration mvArgs path.
sometimes the codes run without any problem but mostly it shows this error "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"

I want someone help me, and lead me to run it without any problems.

Comment: See also [_Getting Started with JavaFX_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in the [tag:javafx] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).